# rounded corners on a thumbnail

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make the corners of a thumbnail rounded using css?

EDIT - The html starting point is:

```
<img src='test.jpg' width='50' height='50' />
```

It has no css on it at the start and I be wanting to round the corners a little...

EDIT+NOTE:  The moz-border method doesn't really round the corners of the image itself, which is what I was hoping for, instead it rounds the corners of a boarder square around the images.  Looks ok...

Comment: thumbnail of an image or icon in address bar?

Comment: thumbnail (basically an image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand @Clayton's answer:

You can do it natively in **any** modern browser:

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

The vendor prefix `-moz` will likely disappear soon.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wmYC/) to see it in action.  Notice, also, that the rounding is applied directly to the `<img>` element.

This works in all current versions of all 5 major browsers.

Comment: +1 but I consider Lynx as a major browser, I use it all the time. :)

Comment: @Radek ha!  Hmm, I think the real problem is showing the thumbnail itself, then, not the rounding of the corners ;)

Comment: the real real problem is that Lynx doesn't support CSS at all. :)

Answer (score 1):

To phrase this better, the following two lines will achieve the desired effect in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9.

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

More information can be found here:
http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

To accomplish this in IE8, you will need to use javascript.  This jquery plugin would do the trick: http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Comment: WebKit does not need the prefix. `border-radius` is just fine for WebKit browsers.

Comment: And even IE9 with border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;

Comment: it doesn't need a div.  This can be applied directly to the `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes using the nifty-corners technique. Nifty corners is an old way to produce rounded edges.  It will function in all browsers (old and new browsers)

http://www.html.it/articoli/nifty/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border-radius`. It doesn't work on `<img>` elements, but you could apply `border-radius` to a `<div>` with the image as the background-image.

Answer (score 0):

This code will round all four corners and it also supports Opera.

```
img { -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; }
```

Clayton's solution only rounds the top two corners, which may or may not be what you're looking for.